# h:outputText not rendering HTML from XML response in spite of escape="false"

Tags: jsf, html-escape

I have the following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.shortDescription}" escape="false" />
```

The result is:

> <p><b>Location. </b> <br /> a

The string from `#{bean.shortDescription}` is being taken from an XML response that is escaped:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt; a
```

If I make the same output text as above, but instead of taking the response from the XML, I just put the escaped string that comes from the response, e.g.:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt; a" escape="false" />
```

Then the result is:

> **Location.**  
>  a

How can I properly render the HTML tags I get from the XML? I do not want to escape them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your text is **already** escaped. The `escape="false"` doesn't *unescape* text. It just prints the text as-is instead of escaping it. However, as your text is already escaped from beginning on, it appears in escaped form. Remove the `escape="false"` and you'll see that it will be double-escaped. I.e. every `&` becomes `&amp;`.

You need to unescape it beforehand. The [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) `StringEscapeUtils` may come handy.

```
String unescapedShortDescription = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(shortDescription);
```

Then, you can use `<h:outputText escape="false">` to print it as-is.

Comment: Had a bit of a trouble setting up `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;`, but it works none-the-less. Thank you dear sir !